# Xamarin.ios send sms user access permission

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to know how configure my Xamarin.ios application to acquire a user access permission to send SMS, and where can i find the complete permission list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can send an SMS, the only thing you can do is compose a message is to create a URI like `Device.OpenUrl("sms:123456789&body=sometext");` or use the [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller).

As far as I know there is no special permission needed for it.
For a complete list of permission and the how and why on iOS 10, [read this](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf).

> iOS helps prevent apps from accessing a user’s personal information without permission. Additionally, in Settings, users can see which apps they have permitted to access certain information, as well as grant or revoke any future access. This includes access to:
>
> - Contacts
> - Microphone
> - Calendars
> - Camera
> - Reminders
> - HomeKit
> - Photos
> - Health
> - Motion activity and fitness
> - Speech recognition
> - Location Services
> - Bluetooth sharing
> - Media Library
> - Social media accounts, such as Twitter and Facebook
>
> If the user signs in to iCloud, apps are granted access by default to iCloud Drive. Users may control each app’s access under iCloud in Settings. Additionally, iOS provides restrictions that prevent data movement between apps and accounts installed by MDM and those installed by the user.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the plugin [Xam.Plugins.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Messaging/3.2.1/) into xamarin.forms app to send SMS from both Android and IOS devices, the message sent successfully from Android devices after checking the permission SEND_SMS, but it fails with IOS devices is there is some kind of permissions nedded with IOS?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Look closely at the logs. There shouldn't be any permissions necessary on iOS.

Comment: Abdelrahman, did you resolve this problem?  I am having the same issue.  Thank you